# Certificate issue with Python3 on OSX

Tags: mac, python, ssl, certificate

I've the same python issue as multiple users with OSX, that appears when I'm trying to access anything via https.

> ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
>   failed (_ssl.c:749)

I'm aware of the following solution (accepted response): 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098126/mac-osx-python-ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify.

But unfortunately, if I don't have a folder such as:

```
/Applications/Python 3.6/ReadMe.rtf
```

Hence I don't how to proceed. 
Particularly when I've installed python3 I did it through using

```
brew install python3
```

I also tried to up the command

```
brew upgrade python3
```

But it hasn't changed anything. Furthermore strange enough, according to brew now I have python 3.7.2.1 installed as it returns the following error if I try again to upgrade:

```
Tommasos-MBP:~ tommaso$ brew upgrade python3
Error: python3 3.7.2_1 already installed
```

But if I check the python3 version of my computer I get this.

```
Tommasos-MBP:~ tommaso$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.3
```

How should I proceed and why brew think that I've 3.7 installed while Python is still 3.6?

EDIT
If I run Brew doctor I get the following:

> Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew
>   directories. `./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to
>   determine if software packages are installed, and what additional
>   flags to use when compiling and linking.
>
> Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed
>   via Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew
>   provided script of the same name. We found the following "config"
>   scripts:
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6m-config
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3-config
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6-config
>
> Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar Leaving kegs unlinked
>   can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on those kegs to
>   fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:   python
>   berkeley-db

Comment: Please read the info in `brew info python`. If you run `which -a python` or `which -a python3` you'll see where the binaries are stored, and which ones take preference. You might have to adjust your `PATH` accordingly. Where does your current Python 3.6.3 come from, anyway?

Comment: Thank you for answering! I didn't know about the command brew info python! When I run `which -a python3`  I get the following: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3`
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3`
`/usr/local/bin/python3`

Comment: Did you install this 3.6 version at some point? Please run `brew doctor`… it might tell you what to do about that Python 3.6. If you don't need it, I'd recommend uninstalling that and working with Homebrew Python only. It might require completely deleting the `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/` folder and reinstalling the Homebrew Python.

Comment: See edit in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running several versions of Python 3:

- One installed via the official installer, into `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/` and `/Applications/Python 3.6` (3.6)
- One through Homebrew via `brew install python` (3.7)

These may conflict. You only need one of them anyway. I'd recommend uninstalling the first one and working with Homebrew Python only. Then you can at least be sure where potential Python issues come from.

To perform the uninstallation, you have to remove the two folders, reload your shell. You may also have to remove symlinks that still point to this Python version, which you can find with:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep 'Python.framework/Versions/3.6'
```

Then, run `brew reinstall python`.

Note that your new Python 3.7 version (through Homebrew) will live in `/usr/local/bin/python3`, so make sure your `$PATH` contains this directory, and that you call `python3` when you want Homebrew's Python.

You may also choose to use `python` for the 3.7 version. In this case, please read the note about "unversioned symlinks" in `brew info python`.

Comment: Thank you so much, just one question. Do I need to download again all the packages that I was using before deleting the official installer folder or they still exist? If so, how can I access them?

Comment: You need to re-install them with `pip`. I'd run `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt` before you uninstall the old version. This will give you the output in a format that can be reinstalled at any time with `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`. Make sure that `pip3 list` actually outputs something and that `pip3` correctly points to your old installation.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I fix this bug by running this python script from [marschhuynh](https://gist.github.com/marschhuynh).

This is the best solution I know :D

- Script : https://gist.github.com/marschhuynh/31c9375fc34a3e20c2d3b9eb8131d8f3

Have a nice day !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).